# How to redirect to another site in Spring MVC JavaEE

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-mvc, jstl

I've been googling a while and I couldn't find a clear answer or documentation about this specific method.

I want to redirect to another site, like stackoverflow.com using this method... But I don't know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirectTravelocity", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private ModelAndView processForm()
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView( "redirect:stackoverflow.com" );
    Map<String, Object> model = modelAndView.getModel();

    model.put( "error", "this.is.my.error.code" );
    return new ModelAndView( "redirect:stackoverflow.com", model );
}
```

It doesn't work, it redirects within my site and it crashes... I know this is stupid but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirectTravelocity", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private String processForm()
{
    return "redirect:http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

Comment: Maybe another option is to set the HttpResponse header and set the return type to void. something like: @RequestMapping(value = "/redirectTravelocity", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private void processForm(HttpServletResponse response)
{
    response.setRedirectUrl("http://xxx");
}

Answer (score 0):

change `redirect:stackoverflow.com` to `redirect:http://stackoverflow.com`